# Wso2 identity server how to map scope with service provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have developed a custom grant type using the sample code provided by wso2 documentation https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/writing-a-custom-oauth-2.0-grant-type/. How we can map oidc claim to service provider and after generating access token based on the scope how can I get the claims while validating token. I have created custom token validator where I wanted to use scope claims wile validating token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the how to configure claims for a service provider from [1]. Also in your question you mentioned that you want to configure OIDC scopes with claims. You can refer [2] and in that you can find a topic called "**Click to view vital information when configuring claims for an OpenID Connect Service Provider**". Here you can refer the configurations that you need to configure.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-claims-for-a-service-provider/

[2] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-claims-for-a-service-provider/#claim-mapping

Comment: Hi thank you I have a question regarding token validator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191333/in-wso2-identity-server-how-to-fetch-soap-haders-from-token-validator-api, can you please help

Answer (score 1):

I have followed this(https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/handling-custom-claims-with-openid-connect-in-wso2-identity-server-56d3b6e4319b) article which clearly defines mapping of local and oidc scope and also service provder